# Is System.nanoTime() a constant time operation?

Tags: java

I’m trying to track down the native code for System’s nanoTime() method. I’m particularly interested in knowing whether it’s a constant time operation. Incidentally, I’m also curious to know how one might measure the time it takes for the method to execute.

**EDIT:**

I’m aware that any question of the method being constant time relies on there being some ‘n’ value. I don’t know how the method works, so was wondering if there might be some ‘n’ value upon which the method depends, written in the code. Any pointers towards the native code would be great.

Comment: Relevant: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/

Comment: Any particular call out to the OS will tend to vary in how long it takes to return based on many factors that have nothing to do with the operation itself.  So you'll see variability in execution time that has nothing to do with the execution time profile of the function you are calling.  When talking about "constant time", O(1), vs some other execution time profile O(n), O(log(n)), etc., there's always an 'n'.  The question involves how execution time changes as some quantity represented by 'n' changes.  What's your 'n'?  If there's no 'n', the concept of "constant time" doesn't apply.

Comment: Where does JNI come into your question?

Comment: @tgdavies nanoTime() is a native method. Including the tag is a little bit of a reach perhaps

Comment: I think you mean "does `nanoTime()` always take the same amount of time to execute", to which the answer is "no", because there's too much going on under the hood, especially at the hardware/cpu level, to guarantee a fixed execution time.

Comment: @Bohemian nah, that’s not what I’m after

Comment: Why would it not be? There's no input to the function (except the current time maybe) and I don't see how it would have to have a loop of some sort. Read some register/counter/memory address and return it. Sure, there will be variance in execution time, but it does not depend on any input, so "linear time" does not apply here.

Comment: Classily, the problem with System.nanoTime() has not been in how long it takes to execute, but rather how trustworthy its result might be and what assumptions one can make regarding the use of that result.  It seems to be putting the cart before the horse to be worried about how long nanoTime() itself takes to run.  Trusting what it can tell you about how long other things might have taken to run is by far the more relevant question in any case I have seen or can conceive of.

Comment: As far as I’m aware, so long as it measures time elapsed, it’s trustworthy. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Flipz then wI hat exactly do you mean by "constant time" in a context without a "size"?

Answer (score 2):

Reading a CPU counter can be considered constant time. Easiest is to check the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b6b0317f832985470ccf4bc1e2abf9015ce5bd54/src/hotspot/os/posix/os_posix.cpp#L1392) of the JVM:

> ```
> jlong os::javaTimeNanos() {
>   struct timespec tp;
>   int status = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);
>   assert(status == 0, "clock_gettime error: %s", os::strerror(errno));
>   jlong result = jlong(tp.tv_sec) * NANOSECS_PER_SEC + jlong(tp.tv_nsec);
>   return result;
> }
> ```

Now, there's no loop and no input to this function. Since it doesn't depend on any input, there's no N with which the function execution can grow.

How is `clock_gettime` implemented? Again, look at the [source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_gettime.c;hb=453b88efe6fa79f5c7c6fccc3a520c75fdd43074)

Comment: The issue isn't about the code or execution of the function itself.  It's rather more about what happens before and after the point in time that the nanoTime code is supposedly returning.  When calling any function as part of measuring very small time quantities, the value it returns will often be so affected by external factors like thread scheduling, interrupts, async IO operations, and on and on, that the code's fundamental accuracy is kinda irrelevant.  If one understands all of this, then it can become a useful tool even for smaller changes in the values it returns.

Comment: ...I should point out that this is all only relevant if you're looking for nanoTime() to be accurate to a few (maybe tens of) nanoseconds.  If you just want an extra order of magnitude of accuracy over currentTimeInMillis(), nanoTime() is a great choice.  But then its execution time isn't likely an issue.

Comment: So what is the question exactly? Does `System.nanoTime` always execute with the same number of instructions? Is it branchless? Does it prevent the CPU from handling interrupts or context switching? Is it allowed to use caches? Is it affected by dynamically scaled CPU frequency?